# B physics and CP violation

Tags: cp-violation

So I am studying CP violation in SM. Experimentalists are trying to study B meson decays now a days. B meson systems involve quarks from the third generation and hence B physics gives more information than the Kaon system. Is there any other reason?

Comment: Why do you need "other" reasons? This is *the* reason. Two generations aren't enough for a CP-violating phase and all systems with just 2 lighter generations of quarks may be described by an effective theory that ignores the heavy 3rd generation and is, therefore, CP-invariant. The third generation has to be included in some way - either in the states or interactions - for the CP-violation to show up.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there are other reasons. Apparently, strong interactions of hadrons containing heavy quarks are easier to understand than that of hadrons containing light quarks. I just read this. I don't quite understand why but I guess that's besides the point of this question.